# Bind the picklist with other objects

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am showing one pick-list  of a custom object on one VF page now I want to bind this Picklist on the other Custom object means, On the selection of picklist record all the fields of another object should display . how to do that, Please tell with any example.

Regards
Raman

Please look inot my code once

Class:

```
public class CaseTypeExtention{ 
    public CaseType__c objCaseType {get;set;}
    public List<Specimen__c> SpecimenList  {get;set;}
    public CaseTypeExtention(ExtentionController controller){
        objCaseType = new CaseType__c();
        SpecimenList = new List<Specimen__c>();

    }

    public List<selectOption> CaseTypeOption {
        get{
            List<selectOption> CaseTypeName =new List<selectOption>();
            CaseTypeName.add(new selectOption('None', 'None'));
            for (CaseType__c cn : [select  Name , CaseTypeName__c from CaseType__c])
                CaseTypeName.add(new selectOption(cn.Name, cn.CaseTypeName__c));
                return CaseTypeName;
        }
        private set;
    }

    public PageReference readSpecimen(){
        SpecimenList = [Select Name, SpecimenType__c From Specimen__c Where SpecimenType__c = :objCaseType.CaseTypeName__c ];
        return null;
    }
}
```

Page:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Case Information" >
    <apex:selectList value="{!objCaseType.CaseTypeName__c }" size="1" multiselect="false">
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="details" action="{!readSpecimen}"/>
        <apex:selectOptions Value="{!CaseTypeOption }">
        </apex:selectOptions>
    </apex:selectList>
</apex:pageblocksection>

<apex:pageBlockSection title="Specimen" >
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!SpecimenList}" var="specimen">
        <apex:column value="{!specimen.Name}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!specimen.SpecimenType__c}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageblocksection>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. I would try first with a simple one, assuming your picklist of the Object1 returns ID of the Object2:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Object1__c.Picklist__c}">
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="details"/>
</apex:inputField>


<apex:outputPanel id="details">
   <apex:detail subject="{!Object1__c.Picklist__c}" 
                relatedList="false" 
                title="false"/> 
</apex:outputPanel>
```

The next way is to read the Object2 fields from the database depending on the Object1 picklist selection:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Object1__c.Picklist__c}">
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange"
                        reRender="details"
                        action="{!readObject2}"/>
</apex:inputField>

<apex:pageBlock mode="edit" title="Object2 Details" id="details">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!obj2List}" var="obj2">
        <apex:column value="{!obj2.Name}">
        <apex:column value="{!obj2.Description__c}">
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>

public List<Object2__c> obj2List = new List<Object2__c>();

public PageReference readObject2(){
    obj2List = [Select Name, Description__c From Object2__c Where SomeField__c = :Object1__c.Picklist__c ];
    return null;
}
```

In case you are using `apex:selectList` and not an `inputField`:

```
<apex:selectList value="{!selectedValue}" multiselect="false" size="1">
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange"
                        reRender="details"
                        action="{!readObject2}"/>
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!values}"/>
</apex:selectList>

<apex:pageBlock mode="edit" title="Object2 Details" id="details">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!obj2List}" var="obj2">
        <apex:column value="{!obj2.Name}">
        <apex:column value="{!obj2.Description__c}">
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>

public PageReference readObject2(){
    obj2List = [Select Name, Description__c From Object2__c Where SomeField__c = :selectedValue ];
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I am not using any standard picklist I created the custom picklist by using  <apex:selectList > where I am loading the one field of object1 so how I can do :Object1__c.Picklist__c

Comment: @Raman Updated my answer.

Comment: please take a look into my code once please

Comment: @Raman Add in your code an id to the pageBlockSection: `<apex:pageBlockSection title="Specimen" id="details">`.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: @Raman Sorry, i cannot do your job completely for you. You need to debug your application by yourself. The structure looks good, check the debug logs.

Comment: assuming your picklist of the Object1 returns ID of the Object2: What is the mean by this , I guess I am doing wrong something here, Can you point out please ??

Comment: @Raman For example ID's of the Object2 are stored in your picklist. Or names, or some reference to the Object2.